# Checking whether a set of points in the plane can be bi-partitioned with a certain diameter

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I am working on a problem in geometry and I encounter the following problem.

> Suppose given $n=2k$ points $P$ in the plane. And we want partition points into two group

Is there an algorithm that decides whether we can $P$ into two groups the size of each group be exactly $k$ and diameter of each group be at most given input $d$? I try to use [Linear separability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability) but I get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be mapped into graph partitioning algorithm. There you can use spectral graph partitioning algorithm.

---

I am just giving you brief here. What spectral graph partitioning does is:

1. First you calculate the adjacent matrix($W_(ij)$) basis on connectivity of your points.
2. From $W_(ij)$ calculate Degree Matrix(D). It is a kind of  matrix where only diagonal elements are nonzero and those diagonal entry are the rowsum.
3. Then find Laplacian Matrix $L$ =$D$ - $W$

Now there are many things to understand how can be this turned into a optimization problem.

Basically our aim to  establish a weak relationship between two clusters(in your case) whose equation is
R = $w_(ij) * (f_i - f_j)^2$ where $f$ is the labelling column matrix in your case f consists only of $0$ and $1$.

So our aim is to minimize this R. This R can be  mapped to $f^TLf$. So if we are able to determine that $f$ for which $f^TLf$ this minimizes our work will be done.

ONE particular lemma is there by Courant-fisher The second smallest eigen value is the minimum of $f^TLf$ for any $f$ belongs to $R$  subject to condition that $f^Tf = 1$.
Taking Lagrange Multiplier as,

$La_r(x,\lambda)$ = The $fun^c$ we want to optimize - $\lambda$(equality constraint)

$La_r(x,\lambda)$  = $f^TLf$ - $\lambda(f^Tf -1)$

If you now perform derivative to this expression wrt $f$ then u will get as

$Lf = \lambda f$ ... familiar with this right.

Now the vector($f$) corresponding to the smallest eigen value($\lambda$) is your labelling vector

**Points to be noted** 1 eigen value allows you to bipartition of the graph. If you have k clusters have to take k smallest eigen value. Now there is another theorem which tells If the graph has k connected components L has k eigenvectors with $\lambda = 0 $. So if you take smallest eigen value which is 0 that will be of no use because the eigen vector corresponding to that value will be constant only. Start from 2nd one if you have 1 connected graph.

For more info: [A tutorial upon Spectral](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-007-9033-z)

[*Time complexity*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348512/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-spectral-clustering-and-why-is-it-so)

Comment: Thank you. What is running time of this algorithm?

Comment: Welcome @All. Hope u have understood the method.  have updated, check from there.